# Oauth v2 Bearer token has Oauth v1 attributes

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have an Java backend app uses Azure Active Directory. I am using oauth2 bearer token to login. On backend side I am searching and using oauth2 attribute "preferred_username" and it works. However when I send login request from postman/insomnia there is oauth v1 token and there are oauth v1 attributes like instead of "preferred_username" there is "unique_name" but "ver" attribute is 1.0.[image]

The token type seems oauth2[image]

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the **URLs** you are currently using to send login request via Postman.

To get **`v2.0`** OAuth2 token, you need to use **`v2.0`** endpoints:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Overview -> Endpoints***

[image]

> In addition to that, ensure to modify **Manifest** file by changing **`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`** value to **2**. By default, it will be **null** for single tenant applications.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

Initially I generated access token with **`v2.0`** endpoints, leaving Manifest file as **default** like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token, I found OAuth2 **`v1.0`** attributes like below:

[image]

In order to get **`v2.0`** token, I changed **App's Manifest** file like below:

[image]

I generated the access token via **Postman** with parameters like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

***When I decoded the above token, I got OAuth2 `v2.0` attributes successfully like below:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sridevi s answer I realize that I need to add optional claim preferred_username as below from Azure Active Directory > App registrations > My App > Token Configuration. [image]

Related documentation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Both are fixed my issue.